# Protractor - Element is not clickable at point error

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I know this question was asked before but didn't find an answer that helped me.
I'm trying to login by entering username, password and click 'login'. for some reason the test fails (before entering the credentials) and the error is as shown below.
this is the code:

```
this.clickLogin = function() {
    var loginObj = this;

        element(by.id('right-tab')).click().then(function () {
        browser.wait(element(by.tagName('iframe')).isPresent()).then(function(){
        console.log("before switch");
        browser.switchTo().frame(0);
        console.log("after switch");


        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Email')).sendKeys("username@mail");
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password')).sendKeys("myPass");

        browser.wait(element(by.name('submit')).isPresent()).then(function(){
            console.log("found element");
            browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click().then(function(){
            console.log("logged in");
            browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

            });
        });

      });
    });
};
```

It does get to the iFrame, and I see the 'found element' but then- before even filling the username and password it fails with this error:

```
 UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (179, 282). Other element would receive the click: <div id="wrapper">...</div>...
```

and I do see the button. it's not that I need to scroll to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements with name='submit'?

Comment: A disabled element would not be clickable. You might try waiting for both isPresent and isEnabled.

Comment: Can you also post relevant part of html?

Comment: apparently there is indeed another element with the same name, but for some reason I'm still not able to click it. will update.

Comment: well, the problem was that there is another element with the same name, and another problem was that another iframe was loaded, and when calling frame(0) it would probably enter the wrong iframe. so using 'id' for the right iframe solved it. @alecxe - please answer and I'll mark as answer. Thanks.